# ORACLE SQL Joining MULTI SELECT statement ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a query I need to re-write to join multi-select statement. I have tried to write this query using join statement but am not getting the results. The error is the Invalid Identifier D_TRANS Code is below :

Comment: `ON   DS.TRANS = DT.TRANS` . Neither of your subqueries has a column called TRANS. So you need to figure out what the join criteria should be and change your code to use those columns. This is your data model and your business logic, so there's no way **we** can tell what the join condition should be

Comment: so what is `D_TRANS`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue lies in the `ds` subquery - you have the following line in the subquery generating the `immediate_actions` column:

```
WHERE  d_synergi_reference.trans = d_trans.trans
```

However, the table you're joining this to is d_synergi, so I suspect the line should be:

```
WHERE  d_synergi_reference.trans = d_synergi.trans
```

As an aside, I would recommend you use shorter aliases when the table names are longer than 3 or 4 characters; it's easier on the eye to read and spot issues, IMHO.

Comment: Decent layout and use of lower case also makes it easier to spot issues. Readability is a feature.

Comment: Yeah, I had to format the code to spot the issue! (Also, I'm stuck with my work's beautifier settings; I miss all-lower-case code! *{:-( )

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the issue. long way to go as I still have many of these codes to join. I joined this project and was instructed to use UPPER Case all through. though I can easily convert it to lowercase in Notepad ++ but sometimes I act lazy. I will still post more of this on this forum. I might need to ask questions

Comment: Wow, sucks to be in your company! At least I only have to put up with just the keywords being upper-case. Good luck *{:-)